# After ForceDirectories statement, Delphi exits the procedure

Tags: delphi

I have this simple procedure but I found a problem, while debugging I found Delphi execute `ForceDirectories` successfully but jump directly to the end of the procedure without executing the lines after it, why is that ??

```
var
export_dir: string;
grd_idx: integer;
begin
  export_dir := 'c:\app1\export\';
  SysUtils.ForceDirectories(export_dir);

  showmessage('this line executed then it jump to the end !!');

  for grd_idx := 0 to pred(pagecontrol1.ActivePage.ComponentCount) do begin

    if (pagecontrol1.ActivePage.components[grd_idx] is Tmycomp) then
  ExportToExcel(export_dir+(pagecontrol1.ActivePage.components[grd_idx] as Tmycomp).Name, (pagecontrol1.ActivePage.components[grd_idx] as Tmycomp),
    true, true, true, 'xlsx');

  end;

end;
```

I use Delphi XE5, 64bit project

Update:
I noticed also placing break points on the line after showmessage has an x icon for invalid break point instead of the little red icon for valid break point so I traced from the beginning of the procedure and I can confirm starting from the line begin with the `For` loop it does not get executed.

ExportToExcel is a built in procedure for exporting data to Excel.

Comment: I just tested on XE4 with a 64 bit executable and the code ran as expected. Can you create a full SSCCE console app that duplicates the behavior?

Comment: What version of Windows, and are you running as an administrator? If the `C:\app1` folder does not exist, it must be created first before the `export` folder can be, and a non-admin user can't create folders off the root of `C:` under Windows Vista and above with UAC enabled. You're not checking the return value of `ForceDirectories` (or you could simply build with debug DCUs and step into the call to see why it's failing).

Comment: @KenWhite Win7 64bit as Admin, folders created successfully and I stepped through the code it jump from that line to `end;`!!!

Comment: I can't replicate it (see my answer). Again, my suggestion is to build with debug DCUs and step into the call to ForceDirectories to see what's happening.

Comment: Wait - now you've changed your question and the `ShowMessage` indeed executes, but now the error happens on the line after? Where **EXACTLY** is the problem occurring? If you keep moving the question, it's extremely hard to answer. **Find out where the problem happens**, identify that problem line in your question, and we can probably help. Changing the information and moving the error isn't going to get you very far.

Comment: @KenWhite yes I added more code and found the line of showmessage executed then it skip for loop !! check please

Comment: I'm not checking anything until you make up your mind, and then provide the necessary information to your question. I have no idea what `ExportToExcel` might do, what you are typecasting to `Tmycomp` or what a `Tmycomp` is in the first place, and you've not been clear about where the problem is occurring yet.

Comment: It is quite possible that pagecontrol1.ActivePage.ComponentCount=0 and code inside of cycle never executed, but i agree with Ken, description of problem is awful and seems author need to learn how to use debugger first.

Comment: @AndreiGalatyn yes I am not good at describing my problems. the componentcount return 0 this was the problem. post as an answer to accept but why the debugger does not even step on it ?

Comment: Regarding your edit: The line after the `ShowMessage` is blank, so of course you can't set a breakpoint on it. `ExportToExcel` is *built-in* to **what**, exactly? It's certainly not built into SysUtils or standard Delphi. If you want help here, **be specific** and **provide the necessary information**. If you don't want to do that, there's no point in your posting the question.

Comment: @KenWhite No I was placing the break on the **For loop** line and about providing information this is the **best** I can I am not do it on purpose, this is just my way of describing a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite possible that `pagecontrol1.ActivePage.ComponentCount=0` and code inside of cycle never executed.

P.S. If debugger even is not trying to go first line of cycle, most probably you have optimizations switched on. Check project properties "compiling/code generation" (and make sure you use build configuration "debug").